# Get Last day of the Month specified in String

Tags: java, date

I have found some answers based on Calendar to get the last date of the month.

I need a function that takes a string as date `2014-04-01 (yyyy-MM-dd)` format and returns the last date in the same format.

if user enters `2014-04-05` I need the function that returns `2014-04-30`.

The code I am trying is here which takes the current date time but I am stuck with using the `getactualmaxium` point and how to use it.

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,0);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 0);


        Date firstDateOfPreviousMonth = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println(firstDateOfPreviousMonth );
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
        Date lastDateOfPreviousMonth = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println(lastDateOfPreviousMonth );
```

Comment: Which result are you getting? at first glance the code looks correct (I would use `GregorianCalendar` directly, but probably `Calendar.getInstance()` is returning a `GregorianCalendar` anyway).

Comment: Increment the month, set the day to the first of that month, then decrement the day.

Comment: @BonzaiThePenguin Why do things in a slow, dirty way when the API provides a direct way? This sort of tricks is what gets you to http://thedailywtf.com

Comment: @SJuan76 I know some developers are terrified of maths, but calling methods which they don't understand is just as likely to cause confusion/errors.  I prefer to keep it simple.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I would not call your approach "simple" when compared with the direct solution.

Comment: @SJuan76 I have read the Javadoc for `getMaximum()`, `getLeastMaximum()`, `getGreatestMaximum()`, and `getActualMaximum()` and the Javadoc for `Calendar.DATE` which is not the Date, but the day of the month. and I agree it's simple if you use those methods regularly. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the following code helps

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
     String dateStr="2014-04-05";
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(dateStr));
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));  
        System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime())); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use Calendar if you can use JodaTime or the new JSR-310 DateTime in Java 8.

```
String dateStr = "2014-04-05";
LocalDate endOfMonth = LocalDate.parse(dateStr)
                                .withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(1).minusDays(1);
System.out.println(endOfMonth);
```

What you can do, is take the start of the month, add a month and subtract a day.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```